# Add multiple marker to a vector layer efficiently

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I need to add multiple (like 20) markers on an openlayer map.
Right now I am able to do that, but I am sure its not the more efficient way to do that.

This is the code I found on the web:

```
var addressOSM = new ol.Map({
    controls: null,
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([lng, lat]),
        zoom: 15
    })
});
```

To add the markers I use this code:

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    addressOSM.addLayer(createMarker(data[i].longitude, data[i].latitude, data[i].id)));
}
```

The `createMarker` function is:

```
function createMarker(lng, lat, id) {
    var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            features: [new ol.Feature({
                geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([parseFloat(lng), parseFloat(lat)])),
                id: id
            })]
        }),
        style: new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Icon({
                anchor: [0.5, 1],
                anchorXUnits: "fraction",
                anchorYUnits: "fraction",
                src: "url_to_png.png"
            })
        })
    });
    return vectorLayer;
}
```

This code works but it is pretty slow.
How can I improve it to be more efficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a new layer for each feature, they can all go in a single layer

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector(),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
            anchor: [0.5, 1],
            anchorXUnits: "fraction",
            anchorYUnits: "fraction",
            src: "url_to_png.png"
        })
    })
});
addressOSM.addLayer(vectorLayer);

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    vectorLayer.getSource().addFeature(createMarker(data[i].longitude, data[i].latitude, data[i].id)));
}

function createMarker(lng, lat, id) {
    return new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([parseFloat(lng), parseFloat(lat)])),
        id: id
    });
}
```